# working with php /mysql the system display error message

Tags: php, mysql, select

i am using php and mysql to work on web development example  but the problem is that the system display an error message about the selection of the database can anyone help me with this problem ???

## client.js

```
function GetAllStudents()
{
    var formRequest = new FormData();
    formRequest.append('getStudents', "getAllStudents");

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
    xhr.open("GET", 'StudentService/getAllStudents.php');
    xhr.send(formRequest);
}


function GetStudentByID(id)
{
    var formRequest = new FormData();
    formRequest.append('sid', id);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
    xhr.open("POST", 'StudentService/getStudentByID.php');
    xhr.send(formRequest);
}

function uploadComplete(evt)
{
    console.log(evt.target.responseText);
}
```

## code1

```
<?php
 require_once('../ConnectionManager.php');


$response = array();

$db = ConnectionManager::getInstance();

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student") or die("their was an error in table");

if(mysql_num_rows($result) >0)
{
    $response["student"] = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $student = array();
        $student["ID"] = $row["ID"];
        $student["Index"] = $row["Index"];
        $student["Name"] = $row["Name"];

        array_push($response["student"], $student);
    }
    $response["success"] = 1;
    echo json_encode($response);
}
else
{
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No Students Found!!";

    echo  json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

## code2

```
<?php
require_once 'Connection.php';
class ConnectionManager
{
    static $connection = null;
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if(ConnectionManager::$connection = null)
            ConnectionManager::$connection = new Connection();

         return ConnectionManager::$connection;
    }

    private function __construct()
    {
    }
    private function __clone()
    {
    }
}
?>
```

## code3

```
<?php
class Connection
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->connect();
    }

    function __destruct()
    {
        $this->close();
    }

    function connect()
    {
     require_once('db_config.php'); 


        $connection = mysql_connect(SERVER, USER, PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());

        $dbConnect = mysql_select_db(DATABASE) or die("their was an error in the databse!!!");
        return $connection;
    }

    function close()
    {
        mysql_close();
    }
}
?>
```

the system display the error message

**their was an error in table**

Comment: Where are you selecting the database to connect to? It doesn't look like you select the actual DB in the connection at all.

Comment: @ Fluffeh i will edit my question and add the class where i select the database

Comment: it seems that the query select * from student is giving problem, can you run this query in your db and make sure there is no error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is that you have scope problems: your database selection has to occur within the correct scope.  However, the correct answer is, don't use mysql_* .  It's deprecated.  It's been deprecated for years now.  If you had bothered to look at the PHP manual, you would have known this already.  Switching to [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) is really not hard.

If you switch everything over to mysqli correctly, I bet you things will work fine.  Why?  Because mysqli is object-oriented, and mysql_* is not, and you are building an object-oriented program.

Hey, I bet you I can turn your code over to mysqli in less than ten minutes.  Here we go:

```
class Connection
{
   private $mysqli;
function __construct()
{
}

function __destruct()
{
     $this->close();
}

function getMysqli()
{
    if(!isset($this->mysqli)) {
        require_once('db_config.php'); 

        $this->mysqli = new mysqli(SERVER, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
        if($this->mysqli->connect_error) {
            die($this->mysqli->connect_error);
        }
    }
    return $mysqli;
}

function close()
{
    if(isset($this->mysqli)) {
        $this->mysqli->close();
    }
}
}
```

Followed by this (although I'm not even sure why you want this):

```
require_once 'Connection.php';
class ConnectionManager
{
static $connection = null;
public static function getInstance()
{
    if(ConnectionManager::$connection = null)
        ConnectionManager::$connection = new Connection();

     return ConnectionManager::$connection->getMysqli();
}

private function __construct()
{
}
private function __clone()
{
}
}
```

Followed by this:

```
 require_once('../ConnectionManager.php');

$response = array();

$db = ConnectionManager::getInstance();

$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM student");
if($db->error) {
    die($db->error);
}

if($result->num_rows >0)
{
    $response["student"] = array();

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
    $student = array();
    $student["ID"] = $row["ID"];
    $student["Index"] = $row["Index"];
    $student["Name"] = $row["Name"];

    array_push($response["student"], $student);
    }
    $response["success"] = 1;
    echo json_encode($response);
}
else
{
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No Students Found!!";

    echo  json_encode($response);
}
```

Look at that.  It took me about eight minutes.  Let me know if you still get errors.  I wouldn't be surprised if I have typos or something, especially with that static implementation you're trying to do in Code 2.  (Why not just skip Code 3 and create your mysqli in Code 2?)

Answer (score 1):

If the first statement returns true, then the entire statement must be true therefore the second part is never executed.

For example:

```
$x = 3;
true or $x++;
echo $x;  // 3

false or $x++;
echo $x; // 4
```

Therefore, if your query is unsuccessful, it will evaluate the die() statement and end the script.

Comment: the problem is that the query must not give an error and it must return a response and i do not know where is  the error

Comment: Inquiry appears only have data or no data,I see you code has no data processing situations,Do not understand what you're asking it to return an error

Comment: if the query is correct which it is the query return the data in the student table if not the system display this error message ... the problem is that the query is correct and their is no syntax error  but the system still display the error message

Comment: i used the fire bug  to debug the code and the system display this message: **
GET http://localhost/studentservice/StudentService/getAllStudents.php
 
200 OK
  43ms 
client.js (line 9)
their was an error in table
client.js (line 26)**    i will add the client.js to the question

Comment: mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student") or die ('their was an error in table: '.mysql_error());

Comment: what you mean by this line ??

Comment: i add this  mysql_error()    and the message become                     their was an error in table No database selected

Comment: Database is not selected, you can query the data